# Testing invited teachers in Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

Is it possible to use the test accounts to test the "invite teacher" feature? I mean, I'd like to have some use cases where the person who is logged in my app is an invited teacher in certain course. Right now I don't see a way to accomplish this as we only get 1 teacher testing account.

Hope my question is clear, let me know if you need further information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify if you can invite a teacher to your class and do some experimenting before you try it with a real Class, you can create a new class

1. Under Classes select the '+' that is near your username and create a class & simply name it TestClass or something useful
2. Goto About and select Invite Teacher

Is this what you wanted to set up?

Comment: Thanks for your response Steve. Yes, but you only get one teacher account  when you ask for the test accounts... Anyway, you can ask twice... :-D